# Tubular neighbourhood theorem

Tags: differential-topology

in your opinion is it possible to get the existence of a tubular neighborhood for a manifold M even if it not embeds smoothly (but only topologically) in some R^N?
Thank you!

Comment: No, consider a "wild knot".  Or the Alexander Horned Sphere.

Comment: Or the sine curve

Answer (score 2):

Counterexamples mentioned in comments:

- Wild knot, obtained by connecting the endpoints of [Fox-Artin arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Artin_arc). This is a topological embedding of $S^1$ into $\mathbb R^3$ without a tubular neighborhood.
- [Alexander's horned sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere).

For more, look up *wild embeddings*.